# webpack-dev-server failing to load 0.chunk.js from Visual Studio

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, webpack, create-react-app

I have a Visual Studio project with a simple React ClientApp that I'm using for testing. The client app was working well until suddenly it wasn't. (It may have broken when I added a static wwwroot folder to the project, but that has since been removed--I was testing with a different React App at the time so I wasn't paying much attention to whether my admin utility app was still working.)

Now for the life of me I can't get webpack-dev-server to serve the React app. I've tried:

- /invalidate,
- npm build
- Changing the ports the server is running on
- Hitting it from a different browsers.
- npm cache clean --force
- Reverting back to a much earlier version of the project when this front end was definitely working

Strangely enough if I run npm start directly in the ClientApp folder the app runs fine. For workflow reasons, and for reasons of just wanting to understand how this works, I'd like to keep using the VS launched version.

The symptom is that it simply displays the Index.html page and does not load the app. In Chrome it keeps failing to load 0.chunk.js with error ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR. In Firefox this there are no errors loading this file, but only the index.html file displays.

I can navigate to /webpack-dev-server and everything looks good. I can click through to all of the individual files from there.

Any ideas for how to diagnose this would be fantastic!

Comment: Another data point: cloning a clean version of the repo and checking out a version that was definitely working is also still broken. webpack-dev-server is only sometimes delivering the files. So this seems like it must be some interaction with IIS Express? Maybe?

Comment: But nonetheless somehow specific to this project because an entirely new project configured the same way works fine.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - if anyone runs into this issue, the solution was to simply update Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions to the latest version (in this case 5.0+).